# Floating divs css issue

Tags: css

I'm working on a small PHP script, I made 2 `div`s and I used the float to show the two `div`s in the same line. But I still have a problem with background because the two `div`s do not have the same height.

This is the  **css** code:

```
.wrapper{
    width:200px;
}
.content{
    width:200px;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    background:yellow;
}
.left{
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

And this is the **html** code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="right">
            sdiousoiudosud sdiousoiudosud sdiousoiudosud sdiousoiudosud
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            iuoiu
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @Jeff I want that the two divs have the same height !

Comment: Edited to include the question. Please be sure to be explicit about what you're expecting when asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "good way" is using `display: table-cell`, as I explained in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765447/1529630).

But if you want to support old browsers like IE7, you can use the following trick:

```
.content{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left, .right{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
}
.right{
    background:yellow;
}
.left{
    background:red;
}
```

Where `10000px` can be any value greater than the height of the highest element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jS8nP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display: table-cell`:

```
.left, .right{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
}
.right{
    background:yellow;
}
.left{
    background:red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jS8nP/1/)

If you want you can also use `display: table-row` and `display:table`, and set all widths. But it isn't necessary. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jS8nP/)

Comment: Where  should i use it?